# How many variables we can declare in ENUM

Tags: java, kotlin, enums

I am declaring `enum` as in the following:

```
SUNDAY("Sunday","Week end","1",true)
```

In the above `enum` I have declared four variables, Is it better approach  having more variables in enum?

Comment: it depends on your requirement.

Comment: It's okay, However Enum is not used to hold variables but for holding constants instead.

Comment: I believe you can initialize variables inside constructor like that: ```Week(){switch(this.name()){case "SUNDAY": this.locName = "Sunday"; /*etc*/ break;}}```
 But constructor with parameters seems like most natural and clean way

Comment: Enums get converted by the compiler to class files with static final instance for eatch enum type, you can have as meny variables in an enum as you like, without facing any overhead

Answer (score 2):

The per-class or per-interface constant pool is limited to `65535` entries by the 16-bit `constant_pool_count` field of the ClassFile structure. This acts as an internal limit on the total complexity of a single class or interface.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, this mostly depends on your requirements.

Generally it is fine to have multiple properties on an enum but they should generally be constant and unchanging (`val` types in Kotlin, `final` in Java) due to how enums are shared around the Java Virtual Machine.

If you look at the [documentation from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) you can see the planets example where they define some constants.

If you end up having a lot of constants associated with an enum you may want to reconsider how you are structuring your code and encapsulate related concepts into their own objects e.g.

```java
public enum Planet {
  MERCURY(
          new PhysicalProperties(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
          new Information("Mercury", "foo")
  ),
  VENUS(
          new PhysicalProperties(4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
          new Information("Venus", "foo")
  ),
  EARTH(
          new PhysicalProperties(5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
          new Information("Earth", "Mostly Harmless")
  ),
  MARS(
          new PhysicalProperties(6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
          new Information("Mars", "foo")
  ),
  JUPITER(
          new PhysicalProperties(1.9e+27, 7.1492e7),
          new Information("Jupiter", "foo")
  ),
  SATURN(
          new PhysicalProperties(5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
          new Information("Saturn", "foo")
  ),
  URANUS(
          new PhysicalProperties(8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
          new Information("Uranus", "foo")
  ),
  NEPTUNE(
          new PhysicalProperties(1.024e+26, 2.4746e7),
          new Information("Neptune", "foo")
  );



  private final PhysicalProperties physicalProperties;
  private final Information information;

  Planet(
          PhysicalProperties physicalProperties,
          Information information
  ) {
    this.physicalProperties = physicalProperties;
    this.information = information;
  }

  public PhysicalProperties physicalProperties() {
    return physicalProperties;
  }

  public Information information() {
    return information;
  }



  public static final class PhysicalProperties {
    private final double mass;   // in kilograms
    private final double radius; // in meters

    // universal gravitational constant  (m3 kg-1 s-2)
    static final double G = 6.67300E-11;

    PhysicalProperties(double mass, double radius) {
      this.mass = mass;
      this.radius = radius;
    }

    double surfaceGravity() {
      return G * mass / (radius * radius);
    }

    double surfaceWeight(double otherMass) {
      return otherMass * surfaceGravity();
    }

  }

  public static final class Information {

    private final String name;
    private final String description;

    Information(String name, String description) {
      this.name = name;
      this.description = description;
    }
  }

// I have omitted some getters from these examples for shortness
}
```

This is a bit of a contrived example since there are only 4 constants but you can imagine a situation where there might be a lot of additional constants.

When your enums bloat you should also consider whether they should be using enumerated types or not, especially if you find yourself adding many additional enum entries as your project develops. For example to add a new planet to the above example above you will need to add a new enum entry and recompile, whereas you could convert the enum to a class and create an arbitrary amount instances on the fly.